# TFS 2008 to TFS 2010 upgrade to exclude sharepoint

Tags: migrate

I'm currently planning to upgrade our TFS 2008 server to TFS 2010 with the condition below:
1. upgrade everything except for the sharepoint
2. upgrade everything including sharepoint but sharepoint will be enabled only at later stage. will this stop us from using TFS for our development?

Thanks,

Chen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharepoint shouldn't be a requirement unless you have a strong need to have project portals.  Everything else (workitems, source repository, etc. should work fine).

Comment: so basically what you mean is that we can backup everything and sharepoint will still work if we install the prerequisite since sharepoint is an optional component?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I do know that the sharepoint data is stored in its own database.  You probably will have issues with reporting data that is drawn from TFS, though, as your Reporting server will have changed.  My point was-- if you're not using the sharepoint database, you can upgrade without it, and the WorkItem Tracking and Source Control will still work fine.

Comment: Cool.. Do you know anything else might be dependent on sharepoint apart from the reporting server?
Thanks